# example of function which is not Lebesgue–Stieltjes integrable

Tags: measure-theory

Can anybody give example of function which is not Lebesgue–Stieltjes integrable? I couldn't find it any book or on net.

Comment: Do you need more than the existence of a non-Lebesgue measurable set, which is proved in Rudin *Real and Complex Analysis* 2.22?  Its characteristic function is not measurable and thus lacks a Lebesgue integral.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest example is a non-measurable function, as in ForgotALot's comment.

But if we require that $f(x)$ be measurable, then $f$ can still fail to have a well-defined integral if both the positive and negative parts of $f$ have infinite integral. One example is $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ on $(0,\infty)$. This example is interesting because the (improper) Riemann integral of $f$ exists, but the Lebesgue integral is undefined.